# How to show text in the news webpart in SP2013?

Tags: newsfeed

I have a SP2013 portal. I didnt build it, but there is a webpart with news articles in it. I see only the title and a read more hyperlink. I would like to show also the first 2 rows of the news article. How can I configure this?

Comment: After looking at your profile, it's clear that you have a very low amount of accepted answers. Care to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

found the solution. When you go to webpart settings you can change the item style. I selected another item style and now I see title, date and intro tekst of 2 rows.